# R: Is there method for finding all possible values of a categorical value in a data-frame when rows can belong to more than one category?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to inspect a dataset to understand all of the different categorical qualities a dataset can take on.

The actual data set I'm using has 100,000+ rows and I have no idea whats in it

For simplicity's
To  illustrate, for the following df:

```
a<-(1:10)
b<-c("a,b","c,d","c","c","a","a,d","b,d","c","c","a")
example_df <- data.frame(a,b)
example_df
```

I would like a function that will return: a,b,c,d

I have tried using "unique" function, but this doesn't work, because it returns combinations:

```
uni <- unique(example_df$b)
uni
[1] a,b c,d c   a   a,d b,d
Levels: a a,b a,d b,d c c,d
```

Doe anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

We can split the 'b' column by `,` into a `list`, `unlist` to a `vector` and get the `unique` elements

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(example_df$b), ",")))
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried, this and received this error, however: : "non-character argument", do you have any insight about this?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet May be you have a `factor` column.  You can change it to `character` with `as.character`  Updated the post.  From R 4.0, by default, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `separate_rows` to divide the data into separate rows and use `distinct` to get unique values.

```
library(dplyr)

example_df %>%
  mutate(b = as.character(b)) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(b,sep = ',') %>%
  distinct(b)

#   b    
#  <chr>
#1 a    
#2 b    
#3 c    
#4 d
```